# file_get_contents does not return correct content

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have pass authorization and logged in as admin, and already opened the page "http://xx.dev/user/admin/inventory/create". What I would like to do is click the submit button on this page and get the content of itself in the controller.

I am trying to get the content by using file_get_contents();

```
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."/create";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

I checked $url and it is correct. But when i check $html, it returns wrong content from another url.

The url should be "http://xx.dev/user/admin/inventory/create", and $url equels it indeed, but the value of $html comes from "http://xx.dev/user/login"

I am confused, and do not know why this happens.

below is the routes:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| The routes for Inventories
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Route::resource('user/admin/inventory', 'InventoryController', array('only' => array('create', 'store', 'index')));


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| The routes for Login
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Route::get('user/logout', array('as' => 'user.logout', 'uses' => 'UserController@logout'));
Route::get('user/admin', array('as' => 'user.admin', 'uses' => 'UserController@admin'));
Route::post('user/login_submit', array('as' => 'user.login_submit', 'uses' => 'UserController@login_submit'));
Route::get('user/login', array('as' => 'user.login', 'uses' => 'UserController@login'));
Route::resource('user', 'UserController', array('only' => array('create', 'store')));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason, is that you need to be authenticated to call "create"? If so, then you will be redirected to login page because you are not authenticated thru file_get_contents(). Since file_get_contents() doesnt store cookies/sessions.

You could do the same via Curl, authenticate with first request, and then call "create" on the server.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, then please accept the solution. There are many questions in stackoverflow, that have been solved but not accepted.

Comment: Sure. Actually, I have logged in as admin and can already open "create" page. I would like to get the content of itself after I click a submit button on it. So, we still need authenticated thru file_get_contents(), right?

Comment: It looks like no matter whether i have passed authorization, if I would like to get the content of a page which needs authentication to open, we have to do the authentication again?

Comment: Yup, because when you log in with browser, then it doesnt mean anything to the server you are trying to do file_get_contents from. Because server simply doesnt have the same PHPSESSID as your browser does. Think it like that: Server and browser are both clients for the other server. Which means, that you must authenticate with both, in order to use authenticated pages.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much. So, although we write the log in authentication check in the controller from server side, when we truly log in using browser, it just log in with browser, not the server, and they do not have the same sessionID, right? so we need authenticate with server as well to use the authenticated pages

Comment: thanks so much for ur patient to answer my question.

Comment: Hi, i have another question about laravel's session. i know laravel will start a session when client request the application. i just wanna test if session is set. but when i use isset($_SESSION), it returns false. I know there is a session there, why we cant use isset($_SESSION) to check it?

Comment: You could do:        if(session_status()!=PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)session_start();

Comment: Sorry to borther you again. the value of session_status() i get is PHP_SESSION_NONE which means sessions are enabled, but none exists. But laravel indeed start a session, why session_status() return PHP_SESSION_NONE, not PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE?

Comment: PHP_SESSION_NONE is returned when session is NOT started. When it is NOT PHP_SESSION_AXTIVE then always call session_start();